# MySQL SUM + SUM

Tags: mysql

I've got three tables essentially:

`hunt_c_users`
`hunt_c_collected_eggs`
`hunt_c_achievements`

I'm grabbing a leaderboard currently only using `hunt_c_users` with a LEFT JOIN on `hunt_c_collected_eggs` but now I need to include `hunt_c_achievements` points also.'

Currently my query is:

```
SELECT
    hunt_c_users.id AS 'id',
    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', LEFT(last_name,1), '. From ', city) AS 'user_byline',
    fbid AS 'user_fbid',
    SUM(hunt_c_collected_eggs.value) AS user_points
    FROM hunt_c_users
    LEFT JOIN hunt_c_collected_eggs ON hunt_c_users.id = hunt_c_collected_eggs.user_id
    WHERE hunt_c_users.id NOT IN ($bannedIDSstr)
    GROUP BY hunt_c_users.id
    HAVING SUM(hunt_c_collected_eggs.value) > 0
    ORDER BY user_points DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

But when I add in another LEFT JOIN on `hunt_c_achievements` and another `SUM(hunt_c_achievements.value)` the `user_points` is wildly inaccurate, and I understand why that's happening (the tables are joining horizontally so the achievements are added on each item), however I don't quite understand how to fix it.

This is the query that is giving me inaccurate results:

```
SELECT
    hunt_c_users.id AS 'id',
    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', LEFT(last_name,1), '. From ', city) AS 'user_byline',
    fbid AS 'user_fbid',
    SUM(hunt_c_collected_eggs.value) + SUM(hunt_c_achievements.value) AS user_points
    FROM hunt_c_users
    LEFT JOIN hunt_c_collected_eggs ON hunt_c_users.id = hunt_c_collected_eggs.user_id
    LEFT JOIN hunt_c_achievements ON hunt_c_users.id = hunt_c_achievements.user_id
    WHERE hunt_c_users.id NOT IN ($bannedIDSstr)
    GROUP BY hunt_c_users.id
    HAVING SUM(hunt_c_collected_eggs.value) > 0
    ORDER BY user_points DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

---

**UPDATE**

I have added a SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac1f69/1

My expected result using the dummy-data provided is:

```
id   | user_byline | user_fbid | user_points
------------------------------------------
1033 | ...         | ...       | 111
1030 | ...         | ...       | 97
1031 | ...         | ...       | 62
1032 | ...         | ...       | 27
```

Comment: Can you provide an sql fiddle with the table schemata, so I can run some tests? And can you post a table with the expected results, please?

Comment: @mind-404 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71a47 -- note the table name changed slightly.

Comment: @mind-404 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac1f69/1 have updated with some 'anonymized' data - as for the `$bannerIDSstr` you can just replace it with a `0` - it excludes certain `hunt_c_users.id`'s from the leaderboard

Comment: I've also updated the question with an expected result from that test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use subqueries to calculate the sums separately:

```
SET @bannedIDSstr = 0;

SELECT
    user.id AS 'id',
    CONCAT(user.first_name, ' ', LEFT(user.last_name, 1), '. From ', user.city) AS 'user_byline',
    user.fbid AS 'user_fbid',
    IFNULL(eggs_sum.collected_eggs, 0) + IFNULL(achievement_sum.achievement, 0) AS user_points
    FROM hunt_c_users AS user
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        eggs.user_id,
        SUM(eggs.value) AS collected_eggs
        FROM hunt_c_collected_eggs AS eggs
        GROUP BY eggs.user_id
        HAVING collected_eggs > 0
    ) AS eggs_sum
    ON user.id = eggs_sum.user_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        achievements.user_id,
        SUM(achievements.value) AS achievement
        FROM hunt_c_achievements AS achievements
        GROUP BY achievements.user_id
    ) AS achievement_sum
    ON user.id = achievement_sum.user_id
    WHERE user.id NOT IN (@bannedIDSstr)
    GROUP BY user.id
    ORDER BY user_points DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

DEMO @ **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac1f69/26)**